# как наложить один фон на другой

Tags: css

а как здесь сделать фон?
хедеру задать картинку , и еще прозрачный фон вверху.
как лучше. чтоб именно к одному блоку прикреплять[image: вверху прозрачный фон, чтоб было к одному блоку]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('http://www.castellobevilacqua.com/image/Castello_dintorni/Natura/Background_natura/2Arte-e-natura.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 10px;
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```